How do I configure my .crt file content in Application.yml?
I have configured my certificate content in my application.yml file
spring:
  ssl:
    bundle:
      my-bundle:
        pem:
          client:
            truststore:
              certificate: -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- ....

But WebClientSsl cannot pick up the bundle name.
NoSuchSslBundleException: SSL bundle name 'my-bundle' cannot be found
I am trying to apply the certificate to my webclient

@Configuration
public class WebClientConfiguration {

 private final WebClientSsl webClientSsl;

    public WebClientConfiguration(WebClientSsl webClientSsl) {
        this.webClientSsl = webClientSsl;

    }

@Bean
    public WebClient myWebClient() {
        return WebClient.builder()
                .apply(webClientSsl.fromBundle("my-bundle"))
                .baseUrl("**.com")
                .build();
            }

}


Why are you trying to do this? It make break the certificate.

I have used the below code to make secure API calls using the certificate.
final SslContext sslContext = SslContextBuilder.forClient()
                              .trustManager(new File(<path_to_certifcate>))
                              .build();
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create().secure(t -> t.sslContext(sslContext));
return WebClient.builder()
       .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
       .build();

P.S : the certificate I used was of .cer extension and present in my project's resources folder. You can try if the same code will work for .crt extension. Otherwise there are plenty of ways to convert a .crt to .cer file. For example, using openssl like below :
openssl x509 -in your_certificate.crt -out your_certificate.cer -outform DER
This converts the file to DER format, if you need the certificate in PEM format, you can omit the -outform DER part of the command.
